# Angular 6 - Child-Parent-Child interaction: Value being updated in html and not in the .ts program

Tags: angular, parent-child

I am trying to make a two way interaction between child component and parent component.
Code in child looks like:

```
onFileChanged(files: File[]) {

    let file: File;
    if (files) {
        file = files[0];
        this.validate(file);
        if (this.validatedValue == 10) {
            console.log(" value is 10!!!!"); 
        }
        console.log("value of valid" + this.validatedValue);            
    }

@Output("validator") validatorFromParent = new EventEmitter();
@Input() validatedValue: number = 1;
@Output() validatedValueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
validate(file: File) {
    console.log("before valid " + this.validatedValue);
    this.validatorFromParent.next(file);
    console.log("after valid " + this.validatedValue);
}

<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged(fileInput.files)">{{validatedValue}}
```

**{{validatedValue}} always updates correctly**

Code in Parent

```
private isValid = 1;
private checkFile(event: Event) {
    console.log("parent got called " + event);
    if (true) {
        this.isValid++;
        console.log("value changed to " + this.isValid);
        return alert("stop!");
    }
}

<app-upload (validator)="checkFile($event)" [(validatedValue)]="isValid"></app-upload>
```

Problem is I am unable to get the value updated in Typescript code untill a new button/ even calls another method in Child where I see updated value.
Such as: (//in child component)

```
<button (click)="testval()">Test Value</button>
testval() { console.log("value here is: " + this.validatedValue); }
```

**the above code picks correct value**

What I am assuming is this has something to do with variable scoping etc..? (or some thread related issue)
as value doesnt update after this.validate() has finished calling.

Comment: Use `this.validatorFromParent.emit(file)` instead of `this.validatorFromParent.next(file)`

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: @HamidAsghari Still same. Whenever the child calls parent and parent updates the variable. The binded-value doesnt update immediatly in Child.

Comment: @HamidAsghari I was not able to resolve the issue. The variable value `validatedValue` is getting binded in the view but not in the component, is there a way to listen to the changes?